# Codeigniter pagination involving selected number of row (dynamic) from dropdown menu

Tags: php, codeigniter, dynamic, row

I'm having a problem with pagination using CI. First, I would like my page to display 5 active records with drop down button to select number of rows to be displayed (5,10,15,...) with pagination(index) too. My problem is whenever I chose (for example) 5 rows, it will firstly show the pagination. But, when I click on page 2 (or next), the pagination will be missing and I have to choose number of row (5) and click OK again. Can someone help me with this?

My code:

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function viewBranch($offset = 0)
{

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('insertBranch_model');

    $limit_per_page = $this->input->post('getRows');
    echo $limit_per_page;
    $num_rows=$this->db->count_all("branch");

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/main_controller/viewBranch/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $num_rows;
    $config['per_page'] = $limit_per_page;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    //styling
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0);">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="pg-next">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="pg-prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['details']=$this->insertBranch_model->viewDetails($offset,$config,$limit_per_page);
    $this->load->view('branchDetails',$data);

}
```

**MODEL:**

```
public function viewDetails($offset,$config,$limit_per_page){

    $callRow = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('branch')
                    ->limit($limit_per_page)
                    ->offset($offset)
                    ->order_by('branchCode', 'asc')
                    ->get();

    return $callRow->result();

}
```

**VIEW:**

```
Number of rows:

<select name="getRows" id="getRows">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should pass offset dynamically in controller like 5,10,15...

Comment: How do I do that? Can you show to me? Thanks!!!

Comment: I figured out that this line $limit_per_page = $this->input->post('getRows'); is the problem. If I changed it to a number, the pagination works well but not the selected dropdown button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use that one.

```
public function viewBranch($offset ="0")
{
    $this->load->helper('url','form');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->model('insertBranch_model');

    if(!empty($this->input->post('getRows')){
     $limit_per_page = $this->input->post('getRows');
    }else{
     $limit_per_page = 5;
    }
    $num_rows = $this->insertBranch_model->getallcount();

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/main_controller/viewBranch';
    $config['total_rows'] = $num_rows;
    $config['per_page'] = $limit_per_page;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    //styling
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0);">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="pg-next">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="pg-prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['details']=$this->insertBranch_model->viewDetails($offset,$config,$limit_per_page);
    $this->load->view('branchDetails',$data);

}
```

Model:

```
public function viewDetails($offset,$config,$limit_per_page){
    $callRow = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('branch')
                    ->limit($limit_per_page)
                    ->offset($offset)
                    ->order_by('branchCode', 'asc')
                    ->get();

    return $callRow->result();
}

public function getallcount(){
  return $this->db->count_all_results('branch');
 }
```

View:

```
<select name="getRows" id="getRows">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, the issue is still there. The pagination will not be showing at first and I have to select row first and click OK to show the pagination. Then if I clicked on page 2, it's gone again.

Comment: I figured out that this line $limit_per_page = $this->input->post('getRows'); is the problem. If I changed it to a number, the pagination works well but not the selected dropdown button.

Comment: It partially works! When I choose row 10, it shows 10 records first, but when I clicked page 2 it shows another 3 records (I have total 13 active records), but pagination will be more than 2 (page 1,2,3..). I think it's because the value of the dropdown is not retained. How do i retain it? For example if I choose 10, it stays 10 when I click Next or page 2.

Comment: I think your pagination links wrong bcoz 13 records are in 2 links only

Comment: Yea...this one I also noticed the issue. Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: for retain the value you can use session or jquery

Comment: I've done that but I realised that it is not the actual issue. Everytime I click on next page, it will execute the else{ $limit_per_page = 5;} part. It does not take the value from the dropdown button.

Comment: https://www.patchesoft.com/using-datatables-with-codeigniter-tutorial  follow this tutorial. its the datatable.

Comment: Thanks! Using datatable is actually easier. Thanks again for the suggestion!

Comment: glad to help :)